# Kotlin java.io.NotSerializableException when sending to socket

Tags: java, sockets, kotlin

this question is already being asked for Java, however, I'm facing a strange issue when I try to send an object across the network. The object's class is the following

```kotlin
class Packet(override val type: PacketType) : Serializable, Packet {

    override var payload: Any? = null;

    companion object {
        private const val serialVersionUID = 578515438738407941L
    }

}
```

As you can see, it already implements the Serializable interface, and it contains the serialVersionUID which I was told by my profesors that is necesary.

I am trying to send this object across the network with this function

```kotlin
fun sendToServer(payload: Packet, sender: Client, receiver: Server): Unit {

    try {
        val requestSocket = Socket(InetAddress.getByName(receiver.ip), receiver.port)
        val out: ObjectOutputStream
        out = ObjectOutputStream(requestSocket.getOutputStream())
        println("Sending $payload to $receiver.")
        out.writeUnshared(payload)
        out.flush()
    } catch (err: Exception) {
        System.err.println("$sender Tried to connect to -> $receiver But an error occurred.")
        err.printStackTrace()
    }

}
```

The error happens at line 22, so the `writeUnshared` seems to be the problem. I have tried `WriteObject` but it did not work either. I want to write an object, not just a `String` or an `Int`.

When I trigger this function, I get the "NotSerializableException" error. I'm so confused about this, it was working on an older project of mine. If you need any more explanation, **please** comment below and I will be happy to **update** this question.

Comment: The exception tells you which class isn't Serializable, and it isn't this one. Clearly it is the `Any` member.

Comment: The serialization error occurred in this object, read my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my own problem, and I hope that maybe someone will find this useful. The problem was hidden inside the **payload** field.

I created a *packet* object with the following code

```kotlin
val factory = PacketFactory()
val packet: Packet = factory.makePacket(PacketType.REGISTRATION)
packet.payload = this
sendToServer(packet, this, where)
```

And the problem seemed to be the `packet.payload = this` part where I encapsulated a NON-serializable object inside a serializable one. If you do that, apparently you will end up with a NON-serializable object, so you can't send it across the network.

The fix was the following code

```kotlin
val factory = PacketFactory()
val packet: Packet = factory.makePacket(PacketType.REGISTRATION)
packet.payload = "BLABLABLA"
sendToServer(packet, this, where)
```

The "blablabla" part, is **serializable** so everyone is happy! (including JVM)

I hope you learned something after reading this, have a wonderful day!

Comment: To check for this at compile-time, you could change the type of payload from `Any?` to `Serializable?`.

Comment: @gidds nice catch! I will do that